# How to test a WordPress plugin on a single post?

Tags: plugins, single

I would like to test a plugin on a single post, where the ID = 12546.

I tried `is_single('12546')` in plugin.php and `$post->ID` with `global $post;`.

Any suggestions to get this working.

Comment: have you tried `is_singular()`

Comment: Also, add more detail to what exactly are you trying to do and how are you trying to do that. It might be that you are hooking to an action or filter that is running before the conditionals are set

Comment: I am checking for a post page with specific ID  and not for the post type. is_singular() checks for post type. is_single, is_post, etc looks correct candidates here..

Comment: I got it to work by following these steps

1) I first identified the content filter(s) in the plugin code.
2) Then in the content filter function I made the condition like this

 global $post;
    if (!is_single(179087)) return $content;